# $2^n$ base $5$ contains more than ones and zeros?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

[This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38614092#38614092) math problem was posted on [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=38614092#38614092) over at [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

It states this: Prove that for all integers $n > 0, 2^n$ will contain a digit other than $1$ and $0$ in base $5$.

TNB came up with these conditions for a counterexample:

$2^n \text{ mod } 5 = 1$ ; $2^n \text{ mod } 10 = 6$ ; and $n \text{ mod } 4 = 0$

Comment: If we express a number in base 5 using only ones and zeros, the resulting value will be a number that must be either divisible by 5 (if the last digit is 0), or is one greater than a number that is divisible by 5 (if the last digit is 1)

Comment: Values of 2^n must end in 2, 4, 6, or 8.

Comment: @AndrewGray  Not in base $5$.  For example, $2^{20}=232023301_5$ which ends in $01$.

Comment: Perhaps investigating $2^n\pmod{5^k}$?

Comment: Also note that the power will be a power of 16; that is, $n\equiv 0\text{ (mod 4)}$

Comment: @AndrewGray you've proven the result for values ending in 2,4,8 but not 6

Comment: 232023301 does NOT uses only ones and zeros!

Comment: @HyperNeutrino  Unless I have made a mistake (always possible) you also need $n\equiv 0,8 \pmod {20}$, to get the least two places right.

Comment: I couldn't think of a good title...
@krirkrirk, yeah forgot that one, TNB already had that.

Comment: Right.  you need to add a proof for values ending in 6, which are all equal to 2^4n or 16^n.

Comment: @AndrewGray  Yes, my example was to show that it was possible to end in $01$ in base $5$.  $20$ is the least such power.  $2^8$ ends in $11$ in base $5$.

Comment: @lulu That could be true; more specific than my statement. I am working on this problem so I will let you know if that's not correct.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino  Sadly, though, extending this reasoning won't obviously give the desired result.  You can always get the power to end in $0^k1$ in base $5$, just by solving $2^n\equiv 1 \pmod {5^{k+1}}$.  $n=\varphi(5^{k+1})$ will work, for example.

Comment: @lulu That is true. Might get us somewhere though.

Comment: Worse: you can always get the power to begin with $10^k$ (or any other pattern of 1s and 0s) because of the irrationality of $\log_5(2)$. So you can't get a proof just by constraining either the starting or the ending digits.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  Exactly.  You can begin and end with acceptable blocks.  Personally, I don't see any reason why a sum of powers of $5$ couldn't happen to be a power of $2$, though I certainly can't find an example.

Comment: So far as I know, incidentally, this problem is open for all combinations of bases except for trivial cases.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  Ah, that makes me feel a bit better. Thanks.  Seems hard to attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume it can be written as $N=5^{a_i} + 5^{a_{i-1}} +・・・+ 5^{a_1} + 1$

Since this equal to $2^n$. Let $n=4m$,

$2^{n}-1$
$=16^{m}-1$
$=(3*5+1)^m-1 $
$=(3*5)^m+・・・+m(m-1)/2*(3*5)^2+5*3m$

It must be $3m=5^{b_1}=1$, or $5^{b_1}+1$. $9m(m-1)/2$ must be $5^{b_2},5^{b_2}+1$. So possible case are two.

$(i)$  $5^{b_1}*3(m-1)/2=5^{b_2}+1$

this leads $-5^{b_2-b_1}=2,b_1=0$. This is false.

$(ii)$ $9m(m-1)/2=5^{b_2}+1$

$⇔(5^{b_1}+1)*(5^{b_1}-2)=2(5^{b_2}+1)$

$-2 \not \equiv2 \mod 5 $ This is a contradiction.

Therefore it was proved there are no $2^n$ of base 5 which is made of only $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch The question is asking about powers of 2, where the number must be able to be written as $2^n$

Comment: Why must $3m=5^{b_1}=1$?

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch Yeah I think you're right, my bad!

Comment: This argument seems to be making the assumption that an individual term binomial expansion has to match an individual term in the sum of powers of $5$ (with a  allowance for the extra $1$).  This is fundamentally unsound.

Comment: I think it is most natural assumption, though. By the way, did you read comments in question?

Comment: I have read the comments, but not sure if you are referring to a specific topic (that the problem appears to be open?).  I don't see how it is a natural assumption.  It's rather similar to assuming that polynomials $f,g$ are identical just because $f(5) = g(5)$.  It's true if we know the coefficients are very small, but here the coefficients are exponential in size.